# Best analytics offering for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

What is the best iPhone analytics offering out there?  I've seen [Pinchmedia](http://www.pinchmedia.com) but I'm not sure about it since the default application page says "Last Updated July 2008".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried several packages and Pinch Media is by far the best. I don't know where that July 2008 date comes from, they've been releasing updates regularly and are super-responsive to feedback and questions emailed to their support people. Whether by coincidence or not, several of my suggestions have made it into the current Pinch libraries

Aside from the excellent support, the reason I prefer pinch is that they seemed to be the only package that updates several times a day - usually once per hour. This is great if you're trying new advertising techniques, or just like obsessing over your sales figures (as every developer does at first :)

On the downside there are two issues I have with Pinch - their website can be a little clunky and isn't very iPhone friendly (ironic!), and at times they've had problems where stat updates aren't available due to hardware problems. I also wish they had an "overview" for all your applications.

It's worth pointing out that all of the analytics libraries are extremely easy to build into your application and all work with both the simulator and hardware so it's extremely easy to evaluate them to find the one you like best. It's even possible to use several at once - though I would only do this for testing.

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays Pinch Media has been merged into [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/). Flurry is a decent choice.

Comment: Is it free? Their site makes it a bit hard to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a quick project 'afterthought' you'll be pleased to know that basic Flurry integration is a one liner in the AppDelegate :)

Answer (score 1):

Google :)

http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/mobileAppsTracking.html

Comment: Currently against the developer agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Flurry is a very nice option. In my most recent app I have tried [Appsee Mobile Analytics](http://www.appsee.com) which I like if you're looking for something different - they give you video recordings of user sessions and heat maps. It's a little more interactive than other analytics

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in visual analytic tools, like heatmaps, or you want to get some inside on the way that your users use your app you should try [heatma.ps](https://heatma.ps)

Answer (score 0):

Quantcast, who is well know for audience demographics measurement for websites, launched it's [Quantcast Measure for Mobile Apps](https://info.quantcast.com/MeasureApps_mk.html) program earlier this year. Their iOS, Android, and PhoneGap SDK is [available on github](https://github.com/quantcast).

Answer (score -1):

At this point you may well want to roll your own - on a constrained device do you really want a third party library taking up an unknown amount of limited network bandwidth and processing power?

Comment: Frankly that would be dumb. These packages are written by people with more experience of optimizing for bandwidth/memory/cpu than 99.99% of iPhone developers.

There's also a time investment needed for this - particularly for any useful type of web interface. Spend the time on your app instead.

Comment: I think the down-votes have been a bit unfair. In some case you can't trust a third party.