# Analytics for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, analytics, usage-statistics

I was wondering what are some good analytics plugins for the iPhone SDK?

Would it be wise to use Google Analytics and have that hook up to the app?

What are my options? Any particular strategies?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean iPhone application usage analytics ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best analytics offering for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406186/best-analytics-offering-for-iphone)

Comment: Pierre yes, iPhone app usage.

Comment: If you want visualise your users behavior try [heatma.ps](https://heatma.ps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple : "Device Data may not be provided or disclosed to a third party without Apple’s prior written consent. Accordingly, the use of third party software in Your Application to collect and send Device Data to a third party for processing or analysis is expressly prohibited…"

Here is a [Tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2010/04/22/how-to-integrate-google-analytics-tracking-into-your-apps-in-7-minutes/) ,If you want to integrate Google Analytics inside your application.

Comment: So then is it legal to use Google Analytics then?

Answer (score 3):

[Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html) recently released an updated SDK in mid-June for 4.0 that complies with SDK EULA changes. It now no longer sends device names and OS/firmware versions.

Implementation is as simple as a line of code in your app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and you can optionally tag specific events as well and add location tracking.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't updated myself with the very very latest developer terms and conditions, but the last set I read (attached to the iPhone SDK 4) stated that you weren't allowed to send device data to 3rd parties for analysis or collection. So be careful when considering your choice.

I heard rumours that apps containing Flurry Analytics are being rejected from the App Store. This would seem to tie in with the small outburst Steve Jobs had during the All Things D interview, when he slated Flurry for collecting iPhone 4 and iPad data before the devices were released.

However, contradictory to that rumour - my own apps contain Flurry Analytics and they have had a few updates approved since iOS4 was released to the public. So perhaps the rumour doesn't hold any water? I Also heard that Flurry had updated their SDK and removed the code that collects device data.

Just to be clear, only device data was prohibited from being sent to 3rd parties. App usage, and other data may be collected and sent to third parties. Device data would boil down to things like hardware model numbers, UDIDs and software version information, etc.

So just be careful in considering your analytics choices. If you want to see device data, you'll have to collect it and store it yourself using a private web service or some other method.