# Analytics services/libraries available for the iPhone/iOS platform?

Tags: iphone, analytics, ios

What analytics libraries/services are there for the iPhone/iOS platform to collect usage data about my application? At least the following services are available:

- [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/)
- [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/)
- [Medialets](http://www.medialets.com/)

Preferably the library should report as much as it can automatically, but it should also allow for tracking events defined by the application author. Also, preferably it should include some kind of a service (probably web-based) to present the analytics data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best analytics offering for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406186/best-analytics-offering-for-iphone)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229083/best-mobile-application-analytics-package

Answer (score 0):

I use Flurry in my apps and it works pretty good.
There are a lot of informations about the usage of the app, and it is uploaded automatically
by the library.
It is also very very fast to add to your app.

The data are displayed in graph on the flurry website.