# Logging iphone feature usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, analytics

Are there any frameworks/services for logging user usage of an iphone application?

Say you want to log events like 'creating a contact' or something similiar, to know how people are actually using your app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best analytics offering for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406186/best-analytics-offering-for-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

I have used and really like Pinch Media. (Recently renamed to flurry)

http://www.flurry.com

It gives you a bunch of analytics without you having to do anything special.
You can also add hooks to your code to see how often a particular section of code is run and get analytics on that area as well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Flurry requires iOS 4.0 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/) does this.  You can even pass parameters to your events so you can break down which options are most popular, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is simply log these messages perhaps as a Log custom class, and whenever you need to add anything to the log, you would simply add a new Log item to the AppDelegate or wherever you need to store the list of Logs. Then you can save them to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving the logging the feature usage in flurry the url below can be helpful.
http://wiki.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics_-_Best_Practices