# Can I get Analytics for iPhone application like google Analytics?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best analytics offering for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406186/best-analytics-offering-for-iphone)

How to track iphone application?
how to get Analytics working for an iPhone application ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to carefully read the developer agreement before doing any tracking or your app could be rejected: Apple looks finally paying some serious attention to privicy...

Comment: @Malvagio:Ya that is really first thing do ..!

Answer (score 0):

[Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) is my choice. So far I also tried Google Analytics and Bango Mobile Analytics and none of them was as good as Flurry.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use Localytics which is better than Flurry,google analytics.it is open source also.