# Basic local analytics/tracking library for iOS

Tags: ios, analytics

Is there a library that can track (1) which view controller is on the screen and for how long, and (2) basic app delegate events like `applicationDidBecomeActive`, `applicationDidEnterBackground`, etc.

I'd like a **local** library, the data should stay on the phone. This is meant to be used in development, so it should just dump to a flat log file, SQLite or Core Data.

Comment: Check this thread -[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406186/best-analytics-offering-for-iphone)

Comment: Have you tried Google analytics or flurry??